# Angularjs mouse enter event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I would like to change the ng-mouse enter event so only if the user hoovered for more then  a second on the spot the event will fire 
seems like `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"`  is not working for this event

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<button ng-mouseenter="myEvent()" ng-mouseleave="myEvent2()" > </button>


$scope.flag=false;
$scope.myEvent = function() {
$scope.flag=true;
  $timeOut(function(){


    if($scope.flag)
    {
      // do your logic here

    }
  }, 1000);
}

$scope.myEvent2 = function() {
    $scope.flag=false;
}
```

here you can set a timeout on the `mouseenter`, and check if the `flag` is made false by the mouse leave, this logic will only execute if the user has not done `mouseleave` for `1 sec`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set event fire time using ng-model.
You will have to set delay in your event event only. For e.g.

```
<button ng-mouseenter="myEvent()"> </button>

$scope.myEvent = function() {
  $timeOut(function(){
    // do your function logic here.
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: this will also fire even if the user hovered for less than a second

Comment: The reason i want it is not to fire the applay chain every time a mouse enter event has happen - only if the user has hovered for while then he deserves it